# How do I create an Alias for a page URL?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I have `login.aspx` in folder `server-root/System/Pages/Login/` and this long URL apears in Web broswer. How to map this URL to short version: `server-root/login.aspx`?

I mean how to do this through Visual Studio.

I know of rewrite rules in Apache server, but dont know how to do this in VS 2010.

Comment: Finnaly i found: Project->New item->asp.net handler, then add some web.config rules: <httpHandlers>
      <add verb="*" path="login.aspx" type="Test.MyHandler,Test"/>
    </httpHandlers>

Answer (score 2):

Here are a range of solutions to this

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx

Comment: @zgnilec: What exactly is too complicated?

Comment: Everything, I'm bad at english. Just simple: I have link: <a href="login.aspx"> CLick to login. </a> And it souhld open System/Pages/Login/login.aspx file. Can some1 tell me when add rewrite rules?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ASP.NET MVC  version 
you can create new mapping rule for translating the route to page you want

see page here: 
http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/controllers-and-routing/creating-custom-routes-cs

if you are using web forms:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668202%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: I;m not using anything. I just use Response.Write (). Here i found something: http://blogs.iis.net/ruslany/archive/2008/10/23/asp-net-postbacks-and-url-rewriting.aspx , but where to paste this xml code? (mean to which file).

Comment: @zgnilec: In the web configuration file.

Comment: Web.config? It says unknown section at rewrite tag.

Comment: @zgnilec: if you are using just response.write() use this: page as guide http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307903